# Pygame.Surface object has no attribute rect?

Tags: python-3.x

self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
Attribute error: pygame.Surface object has no attribute rect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.